# How do you use a @KafkaListener annotated method with a Flux or Mono?

Tags: java, spring-kafka, reactor

How do you use a @KafkaListener annotated method with a Flux or Mono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot; it is not yet supported; we are hoping to look at it this year; contributions are welcome.

In the meantime, take a look at the [reactor-kafka](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka) project.

Comment: Hey Gary, Thanks for the update once I posted this I then came across this thread ->  https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/issues/100. Yes, I decided to go with reactor-kafka project, just tryna get my head around it by playing with it at the moment.